# Set list item selected

Tags: android, listview, background

i have tried many example but result is same,My requirement is when a list item is clicked then i want to show that item as selected by a color.and that item must be show selected until some other list item is clicked.

tried many example but result is  - when i click on a list item its color change while it pressed after release its color change to default color.

i want to achieve some thing like  [see here](http://www.michenux.net/android-listview-highlight-selected-item-387.html) but this code is also now working for me.

So how can i achieve this type of view.

Comment: You want to know how to make select only one item of the list?

Comment: use the View parameter to change the selected item's background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            for(int i=0;i<parent.getChildCount();i++)
                {
                    parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i have one problem with this code is color of list item is changed to blue when i click on a list item,but when i click of another list item then previous clicked item is also show blue color.so there are two selected at a time.

Comment: thanks  @youssefhassan  it is work as a what i have required.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new xml in the drawable folder name it whatever you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/white" />
<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_selected" />
<item 
    android:drawable="@color/list_bg" />
</selector>
```

And set it as a background for your listview.